# myopenid not working for careers site

Tags: discussion, jobs

I can log in to SE sites, but when i try to log in to careers it does not work.  I get the following:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

Is this a known issue?  How do get into careers?

Comment: It's been very flaky, better hurry with creating an account elsewhere.  Like SE's own OpenID provider.

Comment: I am not sure how that helps me - can I merge the accounts then?  Seems to me that I should be able to access it somehow.  I am getting into SE sites, but not the careers.  How does that happen?

Comment: No merging is required, you'll just add another provider for your existing SE account.  It still works in other SE sites because you still have a good login cookie for them.  Careers wants its own.

Comment: @Uphill, do you mean that Careers also wants its own set of logins, or just its own cookie? (In other words: could one get back into Careers when one is able to add an alternative OpenID provider to their Stack Exchange account?)

Answer (score 2):

It's known now, but there doesn't seem to be anything we can do about it immediately.  My Open ID is completely down right now (at least it appears) for everyone on all sites.  Their website is down right now as well.

We'll keep checking in...

Comment: Please see [Publicise loss of myOpenID](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189701/publicise-loss-of-myopenid), urgently...?

Comment: Their uptime for the past month has been 77%. Yea, I'm going to be looking at other providers... http://downscout.com/services/myopenid.com/intervals

Answer (score 2):

myopenid.com is [no longer supported by JanRain](https://twitter.com/Janrain/status/349576783563202561).

I'm not sure when this was first announced or via what channel.