# How does SE store passwords for their Open ID provider?

Tags: support, openid, password

I'm wondering how exactly the SE Open ID provider stores passwords, in far too many high-profile cases passwords were only marginally protected. I personally expect that SE uses a suitable hash function and salt, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Comment: No salt is used. The only hash is 2ROT13.

Comment: I've heard they bathsalt the passwords...

Comment: They md5 them, **twice**. That's right, **TWICE**. No way you're getting past that!

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know about [the often defunct myOpenId](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189701/publicise-loss-of-myopenid), and the reason to remove my account there as soon as it was online again for just a bit. Nice detail: myOpenId will block my old username forever, in case I forgot to delete some old usage. (At least, they promise.)

Comment: @Arjan yah, well, the NSA claims they _aren't_ spying on us, and Microsoft claims there isn't [a back door for them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSAKEY)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PBKDF2 based on HMAC-SHA1 with twenty-thousand iterations (the latter is set in our configuration).

Just check the [code](https://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Current.cs) (search for `SecureHash` and go from there).

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed that the source is available.

Comment: Hehe, this code says it can do better ;-) `private const int DefaultHashIterations = 1000;` ...but also `if (val < DefaultHashIterations) throw new ArgumentException("HashIterations cannot be less than 4000");`

Comment: @Arjan Oops you're right; I've updated with the value we use.

Comment: Ah, that was not what I was trying to say. I guess in the above snippet 1,000 *is* the minimum, but the error message claims it's 4,000. :-)

Comment: For my own sanity, are we talking about the actual user's passwords here, because I can't make that out from the code :( it seems that this deals mostly with decrypting the user's profile for populating the OpenID response.

Comment: @Jack Yes, it's the actual password. See https://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Models/PendingUser.cs (a "pending user" is a user before they have confirmed their email and is later turned into a real user, where these fields [are copied from the PendingUser](https://code.google.com/p/stackid/source/browse/OpenIdProvider/Models/User.cs#263)

Comment: I see. Having implemented my own provider, I had assumed this was similar in the sense that the provider offloads the actual authentication and then uses the information found inside the authenticated session to produce the response :) thanks for the additional info!

Comment: Is this on github now?

Comment: @Won't No, we haven't moved it yet.